# in html post to php form: when button type = button, how to pass value?

Tags: php, html, button, input, submit

You're setting up some attribute values for an object, such as colour, size, weight etc in a form. If using buttons to specify these values before wishing to post all the information to a php page for further processing - how do you get the values passed to php, if the buttons are not in themselves submitting the form?

For example:

```
<form action="processgivenvalues.php" method="post">                        

choose colour: <button type="button" name="colour" value="green"></button>  
               <button type="button" name="colour" value="blue"></button>   
  choose size: <button type="button" name="size" value="big"></button> 
               <button type="button" name="size" value="small"></button>    

<input type="submit">
```

and on php page:

```
<?php

 echo You specified:
 echo $size;
 echo $frame

?>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The point of a `type="button"` is to be a thing you can hook JavaScript up to. It isn't designed to send values to the server.

Submit buttons are, but you want to let the user pick from multiple sets rather then just one, so you can't use those either.

While you use buttons with JavaScript that generates/updates hidden inputs with the values you want, you really should just use radio buttons instead. They are designed to let users pick one item from a group.

```
<form action="processgivenvalues.php" method="post">                        

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Colour</legend>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="colour" value="green"> Green
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="colour" value="blue"> Blue
        </label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Size</legend>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="size" value="big"> Big
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="size" value="small"> Small
        </label>
    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you Quentin -- the problem is, I'm not sure radio buttons will be the preferred choice of UI for selecting the values. However, I haven't looked into if radio buttons can be customised, eg represented with an img. If so, they sound from your post like the best suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery for this.

html:

```
choose colour: <button type="button" class="colour" value="green">Green</button>  
               <button type="button" class="colour" value="blue">Blue</button>   
  choose size: <button type="button" class="size" value="big">Big</button> 
               <button type="button" class="size" value="small">Small</button>    

 <button id='submit' type="button">Submit</button>
```

jQuery:

You make the form on the run

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.size = '';
    window.colour = '';

    $(".colour").click(function() { 
        window.colour = $(this).val();
    }); 

    $(".size").click(function() {   
        window.size = $(this).val();
    }); 

    $("#submit").click(function() {
        if(window.size == '' || window.colour == ''){
            return alert('Choose colour and Size');
        }
        var form = $('<form></form>');
        $(form).hide().attr('method','post').attr('action',"processgivenvalues.php");

        var input1 = $('<input type="hidden" />').attr('name',"size").val(window.size);
        var input2 = $('<input type="hidden" />').attr('name',"colour").val(window.color);
        $(form).append(input1);
        $(form).append(input2);
        $(form).appendTo('body').submit();
    });

});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EL3PHANTEN/k4sjF/1/)

This can also be done with only javaScript.

Answer (score 0):

As Quentin stated, buttons are not useful for selecting between options, but you comment that you want something customizable with an image...

Option 1: Use `<label for="id"></label>` with a radio button in a table or list.

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="background-color: green;">
    <label for="green">
    <input name="colour" value="green" id="green" type="radio">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </label>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="background-color: blue;">
    <label for="blue">
    <input name="colour" value="blue" id="blue" type="radio">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </label>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <label for="big">
    <input name="size" value="big" id="big" type="radio">
    <big>Big</big>
    </label>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <label for="small">
    <input name="size" value="small" id="small" type="radio">
    <small>Small</small>
    </label>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Option2: Use droplists with styling:

```
<select name="colour2">
 <option value="0">Select a color</option>
 <option value="green" style="background: green;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
 <option value="blue" style="background: blue;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
</select>
<br>
<select name="size2">
 <option value="0">Select a size</option>
 <option value="big" style="font-size: 16px;">Big</option>
 <option value="small" style="font-size: 12px;">Small</option>
</select>
```

[Here's a demo fiddle I created (just signed up)](http://jsfiddle.net/thebeardedbear/BEV5j/)